# weblogic ejb3 two-phase commit

Tags: ejb-3.0, weblogic12c, 2phase-commit

can anyone point me to a good two-phase commit on weblogic with ejb3 tutorial?

I've looked around and found only [one](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14012/jta.htm#i1084720), but it doesnt use XA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[this](http://entjavastuff.blogspot.pt/2011/02/ejb-transaction-management-going-deeper.html) is a good one. weblogic 12c datasources provides us with the XA drivers, and so, everything is mostly configured on the WL console